# is there a sorting algorithm of order $\log n!$

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, sorting

Is there any sorting algorithm that takes order of $\log n!$ in the worst case? I know that this is the lower bound for sorting algorithms using comparison based sorting. I know that there are algorithms of order $n\log n$, but since $n!$ grows much slower than $n^n$, I wish to know of there is any algorithm of this order.

Comment: Mergesort will do.

Comment: Follow-up question: is there a comparison sorting algorithm having comparison depth $\lceil \log_2 n! \rceil$? (Assume for simplicity that the input elements are distinct.)

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I believe it's known that the 'precise' bound can't be achieved for all values of $n$; as noted in http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21152/hardness-of-optimal-sorting , TAOCP has some discussion of this topic.

Comment: $n!$ grows a little slower than $n^n$, but $\log(n!)$ and $\log(n^n)$ are asymptotically equivalent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), $$\log(n!) = n\log n - n + O(\log n) = \Theta(n\log n)\,,$$
so, yes, there are lots of sorting algorithms that run in time $O(\log(n!))$.